# Python do something when Video or sound ends

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, youtube

I want to write a `python` script using `Selenium` which clicks a button when an embedded YouTube video ends.

If there is no way to detect when the video is finished, I would be okay with clicking a button when there is no sound for 3-5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if the Video is finished try to check if class "ytp-time-current" equals class "ytp-time-duration"

For example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

# Just a random Video
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvMUYdr5_g8')

# accepts the cookies
agree_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/form/div[1]/div/button/span')
agree_button.click()
sleep(7)

# skips the ad after 7 seconds
try:
    skip_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skip-button:6"]/span/button')
    skip_button.click()
except:
    print('no ad')
sleep(2)

# defines the position of current time and duration time
current = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[28]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]')
duration = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[28]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[3]')

# checks if the current time equals the duration
if current.text == duration.text:
    print('true')
else:
    print('flase')
```

or:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')

# Just a random Video
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvMUYdr5_g8')

# accepts the cookies
agree_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/form/div[1]/div/button/span')
agree_button.click()
sleep(7)

# skips the ad after 7 seconds
try:
    skip_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="skip-button:6"]/span/button')
    skip_button.click()
except:
    print('no ad')
sleep(2)

# defines the position of current time and duration time
current = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ytp-time-current')
duration = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ytp-time-duration')

# checks if the current time equals the duration
if current.text == duration.text:
    print('true')
else:
    print('flase')
```

Comment: Very Good Idea. But i get a : Unable to locate element: "{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[28]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]"}" Error. Getting the Time with the Class Name also doesnt work

Comment: It works for me, try to write down your own Xpath and maybe use the try function for the ad-skipping.

Comment: you also could change the "find_element_by_xpath" to "find_element_by_class_name" and put 'ytp-time-current' for current and 'ytp-time-duration' for duration.

Comment: At a normal YouTube Page it works perfectly fine. But when i try to use it with a embedded Video it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to start just the web driver and open youtube (with the specific video opened), press F12, and get the Xpath from there. Do you use the entire code or did u snipped things out?

Comment: I tried that but still got the same Error :C

Comment: Are you using the entire code or just parts from it?

Comment: Maybe try to set the second "sleep" to 5. It could be a problem with loading so that the website needs more time to load up the whole page